# Is there a way to decrease the memory needed for the Kotlin compiler?

Tags: kotlin, out-of-memory, code-generation, jooq

I wrote a custom JOOQ generator to generate kotlin classes intead of Java classes.

The problem is, the database that I am generating code for has more than 500 tables.

I need to make some changes to this generator, so I will be compiling a lot of the code it produces for testing. Problem is: I keep getting "OutOfMemory" exceptions, even when allocating 2 or 3 GBs of memory.

#### The Problem

I know that allocating more memory to the compiler is an option, but I will be adding more features to this code generator, so I speculate that the memory needed to compile the code that it produces will also grow considerably, potentially making it unusable in low end machines.

I would like to know if there is a more "budget friendly" alternative to this, if I can make the compiler consume less memory, even if the compile time increases.

Edit: As asked in the comments, I will clarify some things:

The code generation phase runs just fine and fast. The problem lies when compiling the code that was generated with the Kotlin compiler, after 3 to 4 minutes it will throw a OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: From your question, it's hard to see what's going on. Does the code generator run out of memory? Or the Kotlin compiler? Can you provide more information that will help us help you? Here are some good guidelines on how to provide such information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @LukasEder Thank you for replying. Unfortunately I can't give a MCVE, I basically rewrote your code generator to meet with our specifications. The problem lies in the quantity of the classes generated, the compiler consumes far too much memory. Even classes like "Keys", "Indexes" and "Tables" are in Kotlin now.

Comment: Well, I can't tell you what the problem is from what I've seen so far... I suspect you could wrap up your generated code in a zip file and provide that to the Kotlin compiler team as a bug report, though. Certainly, the compiler shouldn't OOM

Comment: Thank you again @LukasEder you helped me a lot. I will follow your instructions, I will keep this question open for a while, if things get resolved I will answer it myself